# Checking user choice independently of locale in android

Tags: android, xml, locale, arrays

I am checking a user input (specifically, a spinner choice) that is populated using a string-array in strings.xml. Afterwards I want to check that user input, however I want to avoid locale problems (the app is in two languages).

I am currently iterating through the string-array like this:

```
String[] categories =  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories_array);
for (String cat : categories) {
    if (cat.equals(category.getSelectedItem().toString())) {
        // Do stuff using the "name" attribute
    }
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve the "name" attribute, maybe using the index of the string-array?